# Stack Overflow error: How would I write this method Iteratively?

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, stack-overflow

I'm getting a Stack overflow error for the following method at the recursive call. I think I need to make it iterative in order for it to work. How would I write the following method iteratively?

```
Node myMethod(String foo, Node p) {
   if(p == null) {
       p = new Node(foo);
       p.link = spot;
       spot = p;
       p.calc[bar] = 1;
   return p;
   } else if(foo.equals(p.origin)) {
       p.calc[bar] = p.calc[bar] + 1;
       return p;
   } else { 
         while (p.next == null & foo.equals(p.origin)){
             p = p.next;
         }
       p.next = myMethod(foo, p.next);
       return p;
   }
}
```

`p` is a Node class that has `String foo`, `String origin`, `Node link`, `Node next`, and int Array `calc[]`. `bar` is an int. `spot` is a random node.

This is what I have tried so far

```
Node myMethod(String foo, Node p) {
if(p == null) {
   p = new Node(foo);
   p.link = spot;
   spot = p;
   p.calc[bar] = 1;
return p;
} else if(foo.equals(p.origin)) {
    p.calc[bar] = p.calc[bar] + 1;
    return p;
} else { 
    while (p.next == null & foo.equals(p.origin)){
         p = p.next;
    }
//instead of doing recursion on: p.next = myMethod(foo, p.next);. I tried the following:
    if (p.next == null){
        p.next = new Node(foo);
        p.next.link = spot;
        spot = p.next;
        p.next.calc[bar] = 1;
    } else if (foo.equals(p.next.origin)){
        p.next.calc[bar] = p.next.calc[bar] + 1;
    } else {
        while (p.next.next == null & foo.equals(p.next.origin)){
        p.next = p.next.next;
        }
      }
   }
 return p;
 }
```

Comment: Also, a name like `myMethod` tells us nothing about the purpose of this method...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth see edits. myMethod creates a node (part of a linked list) and returns it.

Comment: Didn't you mean && in `while (p.next == null & foo.equals(p.origin)`? It does not appear that you intended to operate bitwise.

Comment: I replaced the `&` with `&&` but I'm still getting the Stack Overflow error.

Comment: That while loop does not make any sense in your recursive algorithm: condition is never true. Should it be: != null and ! equals?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Search a linked list for a node that contains foo and return that node? And add a new node if foo can't be found? Also - you need to write while(p.next != null && !foo.equals(p.origin))

Comment: @SamiKorhonen I changed the while loop to `while(p.next != null && !foo.equals(p.origin))` but it's not giving me the right solution when I unit test. But you're right. I realize the way I have it now, the condition is never true. I will edit my question.

Comment: @SpiderPig That's very close. I'm trying to search a linked list with head pointer `p` for a node that contains `foo`. If the linked list contains `foo` then I want to increment the int array by one: `p.calc[bar] = p.calc[bar] + 1` If it does not contain `foo` then I want to add it to beginning of the linked list with head pointer `spot` and do `p.calc[bar] = 1`.

Comment: What is spot? I have the feeling you are doing something unnecessarily complicated to solve a simple problem.

Comment: `spot` is a separate linked list. I need it. When `(p == null)`, the base case the node gets added to beginning of `spot`. `myMethod` is a helper method for building a hash table. `spot` will contain all the nodes in the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Although your iterative-try probably could be written better, this is a good try. However, look here:

```
else { 
    while (p.next == null & foo.equals(p.origin)){ //HERE! Check the while argument.
         p = p.next;
    } //instead of doing recursion on: p.next = myMethod(foo, p.next);. I tried the following:
    …
```

The while loop will stop if p.next is null or foo does not equal p.origin. Now the basic approach would be to serve three cases here:

1. what to do when **p.next != null** (first while condition)
2. what to do when **!foo.equals(p.origin)** (second while condition)   //you did not write it.
3. what to do when **p.next != null && !foo.equals(p.origin)**

If your while conditions are correct (ones you want them to be), you need to serve all cases for which the while loop may have stopped and that should be end of your algorithm. If it is not, rethink your while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely shure what you are trying to do and this code looks like bad programming style but maybe it will do what you need.

```
Node myMethod(String foo, Node p) {
    while(p != null) {
        if(foo.equals(p.origin)) {
            p.calc[bar] = p.calc[bar] + 1;
            break;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }
    if(p == null) {
        p = new Node(foo);
        p.link = spot;
        spot = p;
        p.calc[bar] = 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```